# Restoring Old File of Document Library, versioning not enalbed

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning

I am new to SharePoint, one of our users changed content of the spreadsheet stored in document library and saved the spreadsheet.

Later in he realized that he has put wrong content in spreadsheet and deleted other important content from spreadsheet.

unfortunately versioning was not enabled in in document library.

is there any way to get that old file?

File contains critical information which is required by management.

I am working on SharePoint 2013 Standard.

looking for quick help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have any backup, you are out od luck and there is no other option how to restore it.

EDIT:
But if you have backup of database containing the site collection with the document you can:

1. Restore the database to some SQL server
2. Use unattached content database approach (PowerShell or UI)
3. Restore the file you need

How to do unattached content databse restor see documentation on TechNet https://technet.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/hh269602.aspx

Comment: There is SharePoint server backup and database server backup in taps. no backup was taken using center admin. can we restore it from such backup?

Comment: @Omi see updated unswer.